# vuejs composition ref a dom shows object object?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, composition, ref

I thought referencing an input box to get a single value via Vue.js 3 would be simple, but can't seem to get this working. When I type something and click on search, I expect to see a value from the input box. Instead, all I get is object HtmlInputElement. Any idea?

Vue JS 3 Composition

```
 const searchValue = ref(null);



  const loadSpinner = ref(null)
  const dividendItems = ref(null)


  const router = useRouter()


  function routerPush(routerLink){    

    alert(searchValue.value)

    let url = routerLink + searchValue.value

  }
```

Template

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing" maxlength="10" id="searchValue" name="searchValue" ref="searchValue" placeholder="enter something">
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `searchValue.value`, you are accessing the value inside the `searchValue` ref, which gives you the `HTMLInputElement`. To get the input's value you will have to use `searchValue.value.value`.

```js
alert(seachValue.value.value)
```

See [Ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)

Refs in vue3 can be a bit confusing, by using `ref(value: T)` you wrap a value into `Ref<T>`, so if you want to access it in your script, you need to use `refValue.value`.
By adding `ref="searchValue"` to your input, the ref's value is set to this input, and thefore the ref is `Ref<HTMLInputElement>`.

tl;dr
`searchValue` isn't `HTMLInputElement` but `Ref<HTMLInputElement>`.
By using `searchValue.value` you get the `HTMLInputElement`, and by using `searchValue.value.value` you get the `HTMLInputElement`'s value

#### EDIT (comments)

Instead of using `ref=""` on you input, and getting the input's value, you can two-way bind a string to the input, and read the `Ref<String>` value instead.

It again sounds a bit scary, but the example speaks for itself.

```html
<script setup>
 const searchValue = ref("")

  function routerPush(routerLink){    
    alert(searchValue.value)
  }
</script>
<template>
  <input v-model="searchValue" />
</template
```

In the example I created a ref with value of empty string, and thanks to v-model, it's value will be changed everytime the input's value is changed, so this time `searchValue.value` works. (The string is still wrapped in Ref because of reactivity, so to get the string from inside the Ref, you use the `.value`)

#### EDIT (Solution #3)

I've recently learned about [`@vue/reactivity-transform`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/reactivity-transform), which adds compiler macros, that add the `.value` for you at compilation time.
By using reactivity transform, you could use the code you have posted in your question. (`ref()` would need to be replaced with `$ref()`)

Comment: Wow, that solution is more logically! Thanks I will try it out and check the video out.